# exit(0) is not terminating the program execution in my java code. Why?

Tags: java, exit

```
public class TicTacToe{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("X starts the game");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char a[][] = new char[3][3];
        int n=0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(n<9){
                System.out.println("Enter the coordinates but not" +i +" " +j);
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                int y = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter X");
                a[x][y]=sc.next().charAt(0);
                n++;
                if(n>3){
                    if(a[0][0]=='X' && a[0][1]== 'X' && a[0][2]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][0]=='X' && a[1][0]== 'X' && a[2][0]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[1][0]=='X' && a[1][1]== 'X' && a[1][2]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][1]=='X' && a[1][1]== 'X' && a[2][1]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[2][0]=='X' && a[2][1]== 'X' && a[2][2]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][2]=='X' && a[1][2]== 'X' && a[2][2]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][0]=='X' && a[1][1]== 'X' && a[2][2]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][2]=='X' && a[1][1]== 'X' && a[2][0]=='X'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! X won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Enter the coordinates but not" +x +" " +y);
                i = sc.nextInt();
                j = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter O");
                a[i][j]=sc.next().charAt(0);
                n++;
                if(n>3){
                    if(a[0][0]=='O' && a[0][1]== 'O' && a[0][2]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][0]=='O' && a[1][0]== 'O' && a[2][0]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[1][0]=='O' && a[1][1]== 'O' && a[1][2]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][1]=='O' && a[1][1]== 'O' && a[2][1]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[2][0]=='O' && a[2][1]== 'O' && a[2][2]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][2]=='O' && a[1][2]== 'O' && a[2][2]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][0]=='O' && a[1][1]== 'O' && a[2][2]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if(a[0][2]=='O' && a[1][1]== 'O' && a[2][0]=='O'){
                        System.out.println("Congrats! O won");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    private static void exit(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I have written a code that implements Tic Tac Toe (with baby-steps). The exit(0) is not actually terminating the program execution once X or O wins the game. The program is still asking for the next input. How to terminate the code at that instant ?

Comment: `System.exit(0);`

Comment: you haven't implemented your exit() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your exit(0) is calling an empty method. Replace it by this:

```
private static void exit(int i) {
    System.exit(i);
}
```

Comment: It worked now. I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes. Thanks